# why Switch 2960 does not support "sh env temp status" ?

Tags: networking, cisco, windows

While i am giving command "#sh env temp status" on switch 2960,it shows

Temperature Value  :Not Supported
Temperature Stauts :Not Supported

As i am monitoring Temperature Switches.I have monitored the Temp.of Switch C3560E.It Showing properly.

why Switch 2960 does not support "sh env temp status" ?
Kindly give me the reason & help me out.

Regards,
Sumedh

Answer (score 5):

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12.2_55_se/command/reference/cli2.html#wp1940150

2960's and 3560E's are completely different classes of switch and have different command sets.

Use the 'show env temp' command instead.